# git post-merge hook doesn't seems to work

Tags: git, git-merge, githooks

I have a post-merge hook defined. I just want to test it, so I simply wrote

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "just merged"
```

But I don't have any unusual output when merging.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Are you sure you put the hook in the correct location? Did you make it executable? There's too many things that could be wrong, this cannot be answered without more details.

Comment: Not executable it is ! Thanks, that bugged me for some time. If you want to post an answer I will validate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the hook is executable. In the repository root, execute:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-merge
```